# How to launch a another screen with different functions based on the user onTap

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently working on a Math app that has a category screen which has Cards for different math operations(plus, Minus, Division). when user taps on it displays the next screen with questions and answers. I had create a separate class for question and answer generation and inside it I had created methods for each math operation like below

```
class QandAgeneration{

//Perform the addition quiz generation 
   Map addition(){}

//Perform the subtraction quiz generation 
   Map subtraction(){}

//Perform the division quiz generation 
   Map division(){}

// Generate answers
   List generateAnswers(){}
}
```

In the next screen I want to display the output of the user selected operation eg:- `QandAgeneration.addition()` as widgets and those widgets state changed to display the next question when user press a button to select the answer. I think I can do it by using if else by passing the String value from category screen to next screen by using constructor with string parameter. Then I can do it as below

```
if(widget.selectedType == 'addition'){
    QandAgeneration.addition()
}
else if(widget.selectedType == 'subtraction'){
    QandAgeneration.subtraction()
}else{
    QandAgeneration.division()
}
```

Is this is the best way to achieve this function. Is there any other method?

Answer (score 0):

Create a class for another screen and pass to this screen needed parameters. On another screen implement functionality based on passed data. For example:

```dart
class AnotherScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final data;

  AnotherScreen(this.data);

  @override
  void build(BuildContext context) {
    if (data == 'firstType') {
      return widgetForDataWithFirstType(data);
    }
    return widgetForDatawithSecondType(data);
  }
}
```

And move to this screen:

```dart
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AnotherScreen(data)),
);
```

Where `data` - parameter that you need to receive to another screen.

You can read more about how to work with navigation in [Official Documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics).